# jQuery autocomplete нужно чтобы при клике на вариант не заполнял строку поиска

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Итак мы начинаем вводить что-либо в строку поиска, `jQuery` подбирает варианты. Я кликаю на один из вариантов и данный вариант подставляется в сроку поиска.

В моей же реализации каждый вариант поиска имеет ссылку. То есть при клике я сразу перехожу по ссылке, и мне не нужно чтобы `jQuery` подставлял вариант выбора в строку поиска. Как это можно сделать.

Код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/searchProgress",
                data: {
                    filter: request.term
                },
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (account) {
                        return {
                            value: account.firstName,
                            url: "/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/id" + account.id,
                            label: account.firstName + ' ' + account.secondName,
                            imgsrc: account.photo
                        };
                    }));
                }

            });

        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        },
        minLength: 2,

    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
            .append( "<a>" + "<img class='img-circle' style='width:25px;height:25px' src= data:image/png;base64," + item.imgsrc + " /> " + item.label+ "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

Comment: `select: function (event, ui) {

            window.location = ui.item.url;
            return false;
        },...` Вдруг кому пригодится